# binding remote service from broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a **BroadcastReceiver** named `StartService` which start when the phone boots which in turn starts a service but when I am going to the service from this **BroadcastReceiver**  I get exception:

> android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver components are not allowed to bind to services

my code is below:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class StartService extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private RemoteServiceConnection conn = null;
        private IMyRemoteService remoteService;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, RemoteServiceClient.class);
                                    context.startService(startServiceIntent);
                                    conn = new RemoteServiceConnection();


                                        Intent i = new Intent();
                                        i.setClassName("com.collabera.labs.sai", "com.collabera.labs.sai.RemoteService");
                                        context.bindService(i, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                                }

                                class RemoteServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {
                                    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, 
                                        IBinder boundService ) {
                                      remoteService = IMyRemoteService.Stub.asInterface((IBinder)boundService);
                                      Log.d( getClass().getSimpleName(), "onServiceConnected()" );
                                    }

                                    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
                                      remoteService = null;
                                       Log.d( getClass().getSimpleName(), "onServiceDisconnected" );
                                    }
                                };
                            }
```

Comment: but i want to start another bradcastreciever from this remoteservice how to do (without using any activity).means to automaticallly call the broadcastreciever

Answer (score 0):

some of the step follow.

**Step 1:**

```
public class StartService extends BroadcastReceiver
        {  
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, myServices.class);
                context.startService(startServiceIntent);           
            }    
        }
```

**Step 2:**

```
// make all service related task
```

**Step 3:**

```
<service
            android:name=".myServices"
            android:enabled="true" />
        <receiver android:name="com.yourpackage.StartService " >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I am always used BroadcastReceiver and services this way.

May be helpful for you.If helpful then accept answer.